# Website downloader library

Tags: offline-browsing

I need to put a little project together for myself, and I need some functionality to download a page for offline viewing. Is there a library that will download a given page and its embedded images, and edit the img tags to reflect the local locations of the images.

I know there are a lot of website downloaders out there, but I cant find something that i can use directly in my code.

I have some basic scripts done in python, so Python is very welcome. but pretty much any language will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, BeautifulSoup + python [urllib](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html) module

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

Answer (score 1):

How about python web crawler?
http://code.google.com/p/pywebcrawler/

OR, Anemone (ruby)?
http://anemone.rubyforge.org/

Answer (score 0):

simplest solution I can think of.

```
wget -p example.com
```